# How to link a view´s field to attachment´s field?

Tags: views, entities

I am stuck with links in views. I need to rewrite one field of a view to a link to a field of view´s attachment.

Basicaly: view displays a grid of images. This view has an attachment. In the attachment is a list of [body]. The click on the image should navigate to appropriate [body] in the attachment.

I have set view (with exposed filter, relationships...), but I cannot think how to set up the link. I added field: nid to the attachment, but still don´t know how to link to it from the main view. Maybe I did something wrong, still learning on the go. Could you, please, help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my mistake, it is quiet simple. If you struggle with similar problem:
in the Attachment: 
-add a field content: NID, hidden

-In global: custom text add, for example, `<h3 class=[nid]>[title]</h3>`

This way we have an NID anchor we can link to.

In the block view:
-add a field content: NID, hidden (so our link field gets NID as a value, not as a string "nid")

-we rewrite some field (for example title): output this field as a link. Link path: `#[nid]`

Voila, it works. My problem was I forgot to include content: nid in block view.